# Is there any other suitable database that can be accessed by both android phone and web portal?

Tags: android, database, web-applications

I am new in android development. Currently, I facing problem to choose a proper database software that can keep the information of a user registration details for a taxi service mobile apps.

This app require user to login and the details for both the driver and passenger will be kept in the same database. There will be a admin control the system via the web portal for this app. I am not sure whether SQLite will be the suitable database or is there any other suitable  database for my project where the database can be accessed by both android phone and the web portal?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you're looking at this the wrong way.

If everything is going to be stored on a server then access data from the phone via a service.

You can keep device-local data using the normal SQLite DB. On the server side I'd probably use something else, like MySql, Postgresql, etc.